# How to open Ms Access file with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, win32com

I have an MS access file, In that Access file someone has written code in MS access open events.
whenever open that MS access file open event will trigger.
I have written a code in python to Open Ms access file , But open event is not triggered while opening with python code.
below I have mentioned the code which I have written. Kindly help me to get the solution.

```
import win32com.client

oApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.Application")
oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(r"C:\Python\New Microsoft Access Database.mdb")

oApp.Docmd.CloseDatabase
oApp.Quit
oApp = None
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: do we have any solution for above question ? if we have any help me.

Comment: Try to use `pyodbc`, you can install it with `pip install pyodbc`. I found a tutorial on this and you can follow it [here...](https://datatofish.com/how-to-connect-python-to-ms-access-database-using-pyodbc)

Comment: Pyodbc will not open the access file as per my knowledge, pyodbc will get the data from specific access file

Comment: My scenario is open the access file , once access file opened automatically access file trigger open event. I have opened access file with python code , but open event was not triggered, so give me suggestions I what should I change in my python code